# Emit particles from a plane based on the alpha channel of it's texture

Tags: particles

Is it possible to have a particle system emit particles based on the alpha channel of a texture? I would need to emit particles only from the parts of an image texture that are not transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add **texture** to the **particle system** :

[image]

then change the **influence** from **time** to **density** in the **texture** tab :

[image]

in the texture tab you can change the mapping, enable/disable Alpha ;
by default it will use the alpha channel and emit from the non transparent part

Comment: This is great and it still works in 2.82a. You can also add a color ramp for fall off control.